# Objects are not valid as a React child when rendering an array of objects as children prop in storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a component that receives `children` prop as an array of objects and renders them.

```js
type Item = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

interface IProps {
  children: Item[];
}

const List: React.FC<IProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {children.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

I have created a story for this component as follows.

```js
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof List> = (args) => <List {...args} />

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  children: [
    { id: 0, name: "Apple" },
    { id: 1, name: "Google" },
    { id: 2, name: "Facebook" },
  ],
};
```

And I have also tried this.

```js
export const Default: ComponentStory<typeof List> = () => (
  <List>
    {[
      { id: 0, name: "Apple" },
      { id: 1, name: "Google" },
      { id: 2, name: "Facebook" },
    ]}
  </List>
);
```

But either way storybook throws me the following error.

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For this use case i would just define an `items` prop and pass the items as a normal props, the `children` prop is tought to pass component or elements ready to be rendered

Comment: @coglialoro That would work. Just wanted to know if there's a way to handle that with `children` or even if there is I shouldn't do such a thing using `children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different prop instead of `children` prop.

```js
const List: React.FC<IProps> = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```